# How do I specify P2 causality advice in a tycho build

Tags: eclipse-pde, p2, tycho

I would like to have additional features considered for installation, if a main feature is installed. It seems the [P2 term is causality advice](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_P2_Resolution#Causality). Does anyone know how to formulate this advice for a tycho build?

Comment: AFAIK, causality advices don't exist in p2. (This is one of the main weaknesses of the p2 Wiki: I doesn't separate between plans and actually implemented features.)